# Restore a SQL Server backup utilising SQL backup and FTP to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I currently use SQL Backup and FTP to manage backing up my MS SQL server Databases. I find the solution really easy and dependable to create backups. Now I can restore the backups of the existing databases to the same server with ease, using either the differential backup or the full backup.

I am trying to understand how I can use the full backups created by SQL backup and FTP to restore them on another server. For example if my production server died I could use the backup to restore on another instance as a last resort. Now I need to test this theory, I have tried using MS SQL Management Studio to Task->Restore->Database but it fails every time.

The error I receive:

> BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup.

Using SQL Server 2019 and MS SQL Management Studio v18.4.

Comment: It seems you may have the tail-log backup option checked. Uncheck it for this use case.

Comment: By SQL Backup, are you referring to Redgate's [SQL Backup](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/) or do you mean a back up of your SQL database?

Comment: Dan you was spot on - worked perfect after de selecting tail-log backup option